# Determine the number of six-digit odd positive integers with exactly one zero and where all digits in the number are different

Tags: number-theory

Determine the number of six-digit
a)  odd positive integers with exactly one zero and where all digits in the number are different
b) the number of positive six-digit integers with exactly one one or two zeros.

I have got that there are 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 sex-digit odd numbers, and there are 9 * 7 * 8 * 6 * 5 * 5 odd sex digit numbers but I don't know the rest.

Comment: Surrounding a word or group of words with single asterisks like `*italics*` causes words to be in *italics*.  Surrounding a word or group of words with double asterisks like `**bold**` causes words to be in **bold**.  Asterisks should not be used as multiplication in ascii on this site since they are instead used for formatting.  Instead, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$ for multiplication, e.g. as `$9\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 5$` giving $9\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of exactly one zero.

We have available six positions, each of which must be filled.

$$\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}$$

Choose the final digit.  It must be odd.  There are $5$ choices (*1,3,5,7,9*)

For example, we might have chosen the digit $3$ to be the final digit, which would make our current choices make the number look like this:

$$\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~3~}$$

Next, choose the position of the $0$.  It must not be the final digit or the leading digit.  There are $4$ choices where it may go (*second, third, fourth, or fifth position*)

For example, we might have chosen the digit $0$ to take the third position from the left.  That would make our current choices make the number look like this:

$$\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~0~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~3~}$$

From left-to-right, choose the digit occupying each remaining unused position noting that it may not be any of the previously selected digits.  There are $8,7,6,$ and $5$ choices for these respectively.  (*The first of which we have available each of the digits except $0$ and except whatever was chosen as the final digit regardless which it happened to be, leaving $8$ choices.  The next of which we have available each of the digits except $0$, except whatever was chosen as the final digit, and except whatever was chosen as the leading digit, regardless what those happened to be leaving $7$ choices and so on...*)

For example, at this point we have available the eight digits $\{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ t use.  If we were to choose the first remaining position to be the digit $1$ that would make our number look like this:

$$\underline{~1~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~0~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~~~}~~\underline{~3~}$$

We can continue filling in the spaces with the remaining unused digits as need be to arrive at a final example of a six-digit odd number with exactly one zero.

By noting that these steps adequately follow the requirements to use the multiplication principle/rule of product, we can multiply the number of choices for each step together to get the total count of possible six-digit odd numbers with exactly one zero as being:

$$5\cdot 4\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5$$

The case of exactly two zeroes can be performed with similar logic, noting that when choosing the positions of the two zeroes the positions are chosen simultaneously and neither can be the leading or final digit.

Note, here we used the technique that we made choices for the most restrictive positions/digits first and *then* returned to fill out the rest.  We do not have to always perform tasks from left to right.

Comment: Okay so I just want to know that I got it right it can't be the leading digit because then it's not a six-digit number and the reason it can't be the final digit is that it makes the number even? Or is there other reasons? Shouldn't that be (9*1*8*7*6*5)*4? Since we can have 0 in 4 places only. Why do you have an 8?

Comment: Correct, (*each*) $0$ may not be the leading digit because then it is not considered a six-digit number (*though it may still be considered a six-digit* **sequence**) and it may not be the last digit because that would make the number even rather than odd.  As for using or not using $9$ in the calculation... if you were to go from left-to-right from the very start, once you make it to the last digit there might still be all five odd digits to choose from, or there may be *fewer* than that depending on which (*if any*) odd digits were used in the preceding choices.

Comment: Multiplication principle works only in the case that preceding choices do not affect the number of choices available for later steps.  The standard approach is to circumvent the issue here by picking the last digit before picking any other digits, as I did above.  In doing so, every step will still have the same quantity of choices regardless of earlier made choices.

Comment: I can write 4 expressions and then add them together but I still don't understand why you start with 8? Are you just putting away a digit randomly? I also choose the odd numbers (the last digit first) 5 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 and now if I want to have a zero as the second number, why can't I have 9 * 1 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5? I don't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: @NegativeCreep edited above.  The point is that once having chosen the final digit and chosen where the zero goes, **given those choices made** you no longer have nine remaining options for what the first digit can be.  You only have eight.  Yes, there are odd six-digit numbers with one zero which start with each of the $9$ possible digits... however if you were to count from left-to-right from the start here, you will not be following multiplication principle correctly as the final step of choosing the odd digit to use at the end will not necessarily still have all five choices remaining.

Comment: Note, in the above, since I was analyzing the case where all digits had to be different, the quantity of available choices decreased from step to step (*the quantity not depending on what those previously made choices were, merely depending on which step in the process it was*) since we were not allowed repeated digits.  For the second problem, the same logic can be applied but you no longer need to decrease the number available each time.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the 8. I understand how the remaining options work too. I just don't. understand how we get 8 because we have 1-9 (9 numbers to choose from), what do you with "however if you were to count from left-to-right from the start here, you will not be following multiplication principle correctly as the final step of choosing the odd digit to use at the end will not necessarily still have all five choices remaining."?

Comment: We first pick the ones-digit.  We then pick where the zero goes.  We have **eight** digits which we haven't used yet.  We do not have digits $1$-$9$... we are missing whichever digit from $1$-$9$ that was used for the ones-digit.

Comment: Or do you mean that it's 8 because it can't be the last digit? Like in your example you did  in your answer. 3 wasn't in the set.

Comment: *Yes!*  You seem to have got it now.

Comment: Yes thank you! You said "For the second problem, the same logic can be applied but you no longer need to decrease the number available each time." what did you mean by that? six-digit numbers with exactly one one is 9*8*7*6*5*1 (if the digits are different and the 1 is the final digit.) Can I just move the 1 to other places in the calculation and add all the combinations together? How is it for 2 zeros? There are 10 possible options for placing the two zeros.

Comment: @NegativeCreep The number of six-digit integers where we don't care about if digits are distinct or not is $9\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10$.  The number of six-digit integers which are odd is $9\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 5$, and so on... We don't decrease the terms in the product by one each time because the previously used digits are still available as options every time.  That is what I mean by "you no longer need to decrease the number available each time"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118221/discussion-between-negative-creep-and-jmoravitz).